# Relative velocity of a particle under uniform circular motion

Tags: kinematics, velocity, rotational-kinematics, speed, relative-motion

The question is based on fairly simple mechanics principles but seems to have no definite answer.
Suppose there is a point particle A at a point X and around it another particle B in uniform circular motion about point A. What is the relative velocity of particle B with respect to particle A?

If I define the relative velocity as $(\Delta d/\Delta t$) as $\Delta t$ approaches zero, then since motion is uniform circular motion $\Delta d$ is zero and hence relative velocity is zero.

But if I define relative velocity as $v_b - v_a$, then it appears that the relative velocity is $v_b$ How can this contradiction be resolved?

Answer (score 2):

You are having a confusion between relative speed and relative velocity. $\Delta d/\Delta t$ is the **relative speed** and not the relative velocity. The relative velocity is expressed as

$$ \mathbf v = \lim _{\Delta t \to 0} \frac{\Delta \mathbf r}{\Delta t}=\frac{\mathrm d \mathbf r}{\mathrm d t}$$

where $\mathbf v$ is the relative velocity and $\mathbf r$ is the position vector of B with respect to A. The change in the position vector $\mathbf r$ in an infinitesimal time $\mathrm d t$ is along the tangential direction i.e. along the direction of the velocity of B. And also the magnitude of $\mathrm d \mathbf r / \mathrm d t$ is also equal to the velocity of B ($\mathbf{v}_{\text{B}}$). Thus both the direction and the magnitude of the velocity comr out to be the same as expected and thus there is no contradiction.

[image]

Here B' is the location of the particle B after a time interval $\Delta t$. As $\Delta t \rightarrow 0$, $\Delta \mathbf r$ gets closer to the tangent at B. In the limiting case, $\Delta \mathbf r$ becomes tangential.